# Why does x = Class() create a new object in python?

Tags: python, class, oop

This is my first programming language, so be gentle. I was doing swimmingly in reading my book before OOP came up and I've been terribly lost. I bought a new book **just** on OOP in Python and I still can't grasp the basics.

First, I was struggling with the "self" concept, but I'm conceptually lost on an even more fundamental level.

Why does x = Class() create a new instance of that class? Wouldn't it just refer to class?

If I write y = Class(), too, how come you don't wind up with two different variables that refer to the same thing even though I defined them as the same thing? Why not have language like "Instantiate("name_of_new_instance") Class()"?

I don't understand what's going on here.

Edit: A lot of answers so quickly! So am I to understand that the equals sign here is arbitrary, like the programming equivalent of a homophone? (homograph?) Why was it chosen that way, it doesn't seem very intuitive. I'm not criticizing it, is there a historical reason? Is there some logic going on underneath that is lost on beginners?

Comment: `Class` is reference to class `Class()` is creating new object. This is python syntax. In many C++-like languages it is `new Class()`

Comment: Question "why" is meaningless here. Python was designed that way. If you want `Instantiate("name_of_new_instance")` you are free to design and implement your own language.

Comment: You may find this useful: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html .

Comment: `x = {}` and `y = {}` also create two independent objects, even though they use the same syntax.

Comment: Hm... okay that actually makes sense kind of. So can I think of it as assigning the variable a type with properties you give it?

Comment: you are most definitely storing an _object_, not a type.  variables don't have types in Python.  though you can also _store_ a type in a variable, because types are objects too  :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that was a typo, but I'm not entirely sure what I had actually meant to say anymore. I was thinking something along the lines of "assigning it as a type of programming thingy" (like a list, or object, or tuple, or function). I had been thinking of variables as something that refers to code you already had in there - is this not the best way to think of it? Am I supposed to be imagining x or y as boxes with code in them? I had been thinking of them more as addresses that told what street to deliver your mail to.

Comment: in Python, at least, variables are just names.  like post-it notes you can move around.  `x = Class()` really means "make a new `Class` object, and then put the name `x` on it so i can find it again later."  you could do `Class()` on a line by itself, which would create the object and then throw it away because it doesn't have a name.  the object creation and use of `=` are completely independent.  most Python features are pretty independent, actually.

Comment: Note that if you have a function `random()`, doing `x = random()` and then `y = random()` results in two different values for x and y, just like `x = MyClass()` and `y = MyClass()` puts two different instances in x and y. It's thus normal, expected and consistent for assignment to not come with a guarantee of equality; this is Python syntax, not math syntax, in _every_ context.

Answer (score 1):

The reference to the class itself is just `Class`. Writing `Class()` *calls* the class, which returns an instance of the class.

```
def foo():
  return 42

print foo
print foo()

class Class(object):
  pass

print Class
print Class()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can see the instatiation of one object member of a class like so:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __new__(cls):
        print 'new Foo'
        return super(Foo, cls).__new__(cls)

    def __init__(self):
        print 'init Foo'

>>> foo=Foo() 
new Foo
init Foo
```

In Python, the `()` indicates a call of the class (or function or method). For a class, that first calls `new` then `__init__`

Comment: @Eevee: How is this 'misleading'? The question was about class construction. Sooner or later, someone who is interested in Python classes will need to learn this. It is not that hard.

Comment: `__new__` is _very_ rarely necessary or useful, but i've seen more than a couple beginners think it's the "real" constructor because of the name.  and `super` is definitely confusing to someone still grappling with the basics of what OO even is.

Answer (score 0):

You've covered functions, right?

Classes act like functions that produce new objects.  `Class()` means you're calling it, and every time you call it, you get a new object.  That's just what classes do when called.

`x = Class` is very different from `x = Class()`.  The former will, indeed, just make an alias for the class.

As for "why", well, it's actually pretty handy at times to be able to substitute a function for a class or vice versa.  For example, the `int()` function isn't a function at all; you're just creating a new `int` object.

As for `=`, well, there's no excuse for that  :)  Most languages use `a = b` to mean "take `b` and store it in `a`", **not** to mean `a` and `b` are equal.  Historical reasons, I suppose.

Comment: I think this is very confusing answer. Classes don't act like functions. This is just constructor invocation syntax.

Comment: classes absolutely act like functions: you call them with arguments and get a return value.  python doesn't care.  it just sees something with a `__call__` method.

Comment: They act like functions when you want to call them. In all other aspects they behave differently.

Comment: sure, but the question was about calling them  :)  ultimately the point is: calling isn't special, and classes are one more thing you can call.

Comment: Question was asked by person who so far has very vague understanding of objects and other python concepts so I think it is not pedagogical to confuse him even more.

Comment: I didn't find it terribly confusing, tbh.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `x = Class()`, you are effectively creating a new object instance of the class `Class` called `x`. This is what OOP is all about.

The `self` variable is used in classes to refer to variables that are specific to that particular instance of the class.

For example:

```
class Dog:
    def __init__(self,name,type):
        self.name = name
        self.type = type
        self.mood = "happy"

    def change_mood(self):
        if self.mood == "happy":
            self.mood = "sad"
        else:
            self.mood = "happy"

dog1 = Dog("Adam","big")
dog2 = Dog("James","small")

dog1.change_mood()
>>> dog1.mood
"sad"
>>> dog2.mood
"happy"
```

Comment: Could I imagine that when I create a new Dog and call it spot, say, that the self gets replaced by the name "Spot"? So spot.name = name, spot.type = type, etc.?

Comment: @user3471004, the `self.name` variable is __assigned__ the string "Spot". The `self.name` is essentially like `dog1.name`. It is specific to the specific instance of the `Dog` class that you created

Answer (score 0):

You ask:

> Why not have language like "Instantiate("name_of_new_instance")
>   Class()"?

The answer is that Python is *exactly* like that language - except that it leaves out the unnecessary word `Instantiate` and instead uses an equal sign to indicate that assignment is taking place.  Other than that small (and meaningless) difference in syntax the languages are the same.

While I like the use of the keyword `Instantiate` in your language because it's very clear about what's happening, I also think Python's design has a number of advantages:

- It's less verbose.
- It is clearer that an assignment is taking place.
- It provides a more obvious place to place any arguments required when initializing a new instance of Class
- It will be more familiar to most programmers coming from c-descended languages.

Once you have experience with a number of different languages, I hope you'll share my appreciation for the clever decisions that the designer of Python made and that make (good) Python code both clear and extremely concise.  Of course, you may feel otherwise in which case you'll find a world of syntaxes available in many different languages or, perhaps, you'll find a need to develop your own.

Comment: also "instantiate" is really awkward to type  ;)